# Resize image from pom.xml

Tags: image, maven, auto-generate

At the moment I'm working on maven project and I'm filling the list of developers and contributors in pom.xml. In addition to name, email and role of developer/contributor I want to add an image of person. In order to do this I write:

```
<developer>
    ...
    <properties>
        <picUrl>url_to_image</picUrl>
    </properties>
</developer>
```

But unfortunately the picture by the url is too big. So my question is: is it possible to somehow resize it? Maybe there is a properties something like ?

Comment: I don't think there is. You'll need to resize it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you would manage within your pom. If possible resize and re-upload the images then update the URLs.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your answer